# Question about measure lemma?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-concentration

"Let (u_j) be a bounded sequence from $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ how to prove that there exists a subsequence such that $u_j\rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and $|\nabla u_j|\rightharpoonup d\mu,$ $|u_j|^{p^*}\rightharpoonup d\nu$ weakly* in the sense of measures."

Comment: Please take the few extra moments to retype a short quote like this, instead of including a scanned image; it is  much better for searching.  Also please include a reference to the source.

Comment: Also please keep your titles as descriptive as possible.  "Surching a proof" conveys absolutely no information as to the topic of your question.  I rolled back  your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $1 < p < \infty$, $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is reflexive, so bounded sets are weakly precompact by Alaoglu's theorem (the weak-* and weak topologies coincide).  Thus $u_j$ has a subsequence converging weakly to some $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.  Now $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ is convex and strongly closed in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, hence also weakly closed, and therefore  $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$.

If $u_j$ is bounded in $W^{1,p}$ then by definition $|\nabla u_j|^p$ is bounded in $L^1$.  So the measures $|\nabla u_j|^p \,dm$ are bounded in total variation, i.e. norm-bounded as elements of $C_0(\Omega)^*$, which by Riesz representation is the space of Radon measures on $\Omega$.  By Alaoglu again, the sequence is weak-* compact and so a subsequence converges weak-* to a measure $\mu$.

Likewise, by Sobolev embedding, $u_j$ is bounded in $L^{p^*}(\Omega)$ so $|u_j|^{p^*}$ is bounded in $L^1(\Omega)$ and a similar argument applies.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: This is such a standard argument that I do not think you will find a reference that discusses it specifically.  The results I mentioned will be in any elementary textbook on functional analysis and Sobolev spaces, such as Folland's *Real Analysis* for example.

Comment: can i replace $L^{p^*}$ by an other space such that $W^{1,p}$ is continuously embeded to it but not compactly ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes, the compact embedding is not used here.  But your other space will also need to be continuously embedded in $C_0(\Omega)^*$.

Comment: what is the space $C_0(\Omega)^*$ ? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou: $C_0(\Omega)$ is the space of continuous functions on $\Omega$ which vanish at "infinity", i.e. the uniform closure of the continuous compactly supported functions $C_c(\Omega)$.  For a bounded open set $\Omega$, this means continuous functions on $\bar{\Omega}$ that vanish on $\partial \Omega$.  $C_0(\Omega)^*$ is the dual of this space, which as I said, by the Riesz representation theorem, is isometrically isomorphic to the space of signed Radon measures on $\Omega$, with the total variation norm.

Comment: and how we prove that $W^{1,p}$ or $L^{p^*}$ is cintinuouly embeded into $C_{0}(\Omega)^*$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: All I am using here is that $L^1(\Omega, m)$ is continuously (indeed, isometrically) embedded into $C_0(\Omega)^*$.  The embedding $T$ is the natural one: for $f \in L^1(\Omega, m)$ and $g \in C_0(\Omega)$, let $(Tf)(g) = \int_0^1 f g\,dm$.  As I am not really interested in writing a functional analysis textbook for you in this comment thread, I think I will leave it at that.